# How to create mpeg2 transport stream?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, screen-capture

I am creating a mac application which capture the screen using the AVFoundation. It works till here. Now the problem is I get a CMSampleBufferRef from the delegate method. I wanted to create a mpeg2 transport stream from this. 
Anyone have any idea on how to create mpeg2 transport stream ? 
Some sample code is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am able to save it to a .mp4 file using :
mMovieFileOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];
[mMovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:destPath recordingDelegate:self];

Then convert it to mpeg2 transport stream using ffmpeg (Command line) using the command : 
ffmpeg -i convert.mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb newvideo.ts




But I donot want to save it to .mp4 and then convert. I want it to be converted to mpeg2 transport stream and play it in the vlc player on another system while the screen is being captured.

Anybody please help me to find a solution.

Comment: Have the same question. I found a way to do this by using the libx264, but this library doesn't use iPhone's built-in hardware encoder, and eats too much CPU.